# Proving the Ramanujan's integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was doing some integration of type $$\int_{a}^{b}p(x)\cot(x)dx$$
I start with $p(x)=x^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ .I was able to do $$\int_{0}^{t}x\cot(x)dx$$ and $$\int_{0}^{t}x^2\cot(x)dx$$The second integral was tough even with the help of hint.In the book the general integral is given as$$\frac12\int_0^xu^n\cot\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)du=\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)n!\zeta(n+1)-\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{j(j+1)/2}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1-j)}x^{n-j}\operatorname{Cl}_{j+1}(x)$$

Which is proved by **Srinivasa Ramanujan** for $|x|<2\pi$ and is written in his notebooks. I'm curious to know how to prove this. I'm unable to prove it.

Can anybody help me!

Comment: Are you familiar with the result's [Clausen functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#General_definition)?

Comment: Yes.I'm familiar with clausen functions.The integral $$\int_{0}^{t}x^2\cot(x)dx$$ even involves clausen function in the end

Comment: The right-hand side's derivative simplifies with $\operatorname{Cl}_{j+1}^\prime(x)=(-1)^{j+1}\operatorname{Cl}_j(x)$ to a telescoping series, so you just need to check the case $x=0$ to see the additive constant is right.